# Select data on current week between Monday to Sunday

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I've query to select data for interval one week (<7 from current day)

```
SELECT order_date 
FROM sales 
WHERE order_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

Further I want to select data from table on current week between Monday to Sunday. How is the proper `where` condition to grab that data?

Comment: What have you tried? Right now, you've shown no work, so it's like you're asking the community to build something for you. That's not what StackOverflow is for. I suggest editing your question with more details, before it gets closed as *unclear what you're asking.*

Comment: my bad. sorry im new to stack overflow, im forgot to post myquery. thanks for advice

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to indent your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem as well as more detail on your research effort. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dayofweek()` for this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval weekday(curdate()) day) and
      t.date <= curdate()
```

`weekday()` starts counting on Monday with a value of 0.  If you have future dates:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval weekday(curdate()) day) and
      t.date <= date_sub(curdate(), interval weekday(curdate()) - 7 day)
```

Comment: thanks, but I found error "use near 'weekday(curdate())) and order_date <= curdate() LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 1",

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ORDER BY score DESC;
```

This will select the data of the past week from today.

Comment: thanks, i've done that before. but i want to get data for current week between monday to sunday.